Segments of a string, doubling in length
Simple task today. Given a string whose length is one less than a whole power of 2, divide it into segments with doubling length.
For example for the string abcdefghijklmno, the result should be a, bc, defg, hijklmno:
abcdefghijklmno  (length 15)

a                 length 1
 bc               length 2
   defg           length 4
       hijklmno   length 8

To be clear, the spaces above are just for demonstration, your program does not need to do that, it just has to divide the string into the appropriate lengths. The format of the output is not specific.
The input will not be the empty string.
This is code-golf; shortest solution per language wins.

Related, more general

brainfuck, 26 bytes
+[[->,.>++<<]+++++++++.>>]

Attempt This Online!
Output separated by tabs with some extra tabs at the end.
This is pretty short so I may as well add an explanation:
+        1 is the first segment length
[  
  [-     Repeat that many times:
    >,.    Go right: read and output one character
    >++    Go right: Add two to this cell
             (This is what doubles the length)
    <<]    Go back to the loop counter cell
  +++++  The cell is now zero so we can freely
  ++++.    change it; output a tab (ASCII 9)
  >>]    Go to our new loop counter cell and start
           again


C (gcc), 58
f(s,i)char*s;{while(putchar(*s++))if(!(++i&i-1))puts("");}

Try it online!

I like the idea to conditionally print newlines instead of changing the number of characters printed.

51 bytes

That said, I don't think you're allowed to force the initialization of i by the caller. So it's probably more like 54 bytes.

R, 46 bytes
\(x)substring(x,a<-2^(0:log2(nchar(x))),2*a-1)

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as a string and outputs a vector of strings.

R, 44 bytes
\(x)split(x,rep(i<-2^(0:log2(length(x))),i))

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as a vector of characters and outputs a list of vectors of characters.

Nekomata, 5 bytes
JxËᶻL

Attempt This Online!
JxËᶻL
J       Split the input into a list of substrings
 x      Push [0, ..., length of the list - 1]
  Ë     Power of 2
   ᶻL   Check that each substring has the corresponding length


Husk, 5 bytes
C:1İ2

Try it online!
C       # cut input into chunks with lengths:
 :1     # prepend 1 to
   İ2   # infinite sequence of powers of 2
        # (starting at 2)


tinylisp 2, 46 bytes
(d F(\(S(I 1))(? S(c(] I S)(F([ I S)(* I 2)))(

Try It Online!
Ungolfed & commented
(def segments
 (lambda        ; Function
  (S (I 1))     ; Takes two args: a string, and a number defaulting to 1
  (if S         ; If the string is nonempty:
   (cons        ;  Prepend
    (take I S)  ;  the first I characters of S
    (segments   ;  to the result of a recursive call on
     (drop I S) ;   All but the first I characters of S
     (* I 2)))  ;   I times 2
   nil)))       ; Else, empty list


APL (Dyalog Extended), 16 12 bytes
Anonymous tacit prefix function, port of Bubbler's J.
⊢⊂⍨1=1⊥2⊤⍳∘≢

⊢ the argument…
⊂⍨ partitioned by…
1= where one equals…
1⊥  the vertical sum (lit. base-1 evaluation) of…
2⊤ the binary representation (one number per column) of
⍳∘  the indices from 1 to the…
≢ length of the argument
Try it online!
Alternative APL (Dyalog Unicode), 12 bytes
Anonymous tacit prefix function, port of noodle person's J.
⊢⊆⍨1+∘⌊2⍟⍳∘≢

⊢ the argument…
⊂⍨ grouped by…
1+∘ incremented…
⌊ floored…
2⍟ log₂ of…
⍳∘ the indices of…
≢ the argument length
Try it online!
Old APL (Dyalog Unicode), 16 bytes
Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires 0-based indexing (⎕IO←0) which is default on many systems.
⊢⊂⍨≢↑∘∊1↑¨⍨2*⍳∘≢

Try it online!
⊢ the argument…
⊂⍨ partitioned by…
≢ the length of the argument…
↑∘∊ -sized prefix of the the flattened…
1↑¨⍨ prefixes of 1 (padding with trailing 0s) of lengths…
2* two to the power of…
⍳∘≢ the indices (0…n−1) of the length of the argument

If porting Bubbler's 16 byte J gives you 12 bytes, how does porting my 12 byte J give you?

@noodleperson Also 12; added.

K (ngn/k), 16 bytes
{(&*/'2\'!#x)_x}

Try it online!
A near-backport from my own J solution. Instead of checking each 1-based index has exactly one 1 bit, this checks if each 0-based index is all ones in binary. This works in K (2\0 is an empty array and its product is 1) but not in J (#:0 is 0 instead of an empty array).
K (ngn/k), 17 bytes
{(|1_(-2!)\#x)_x}

Try it online!
Similar to Jelly (x_y cuts y at the indices specified in x), but had to be careful to avoid generating large indices or indices in non-increasing order (which give domain error).
My initial approach used 2\ (integer into binary vector) and 2/ (binary vector into integer), but I realized that simply repeatedly dividing the length by 2 gives the correct cut indices.
{(|1_(-2!)\#x)_x}    Input: a string of length 2^n-1 (example: "abcdefg")
 (         #x)       length of x = 7
     (-2!)\          repeatedly floor-divide by 2 until convergence and collect:
                     (7 3 1 0)
   1_                remove head which is too large (3 1 0)
  |                  reverse (0 1 3)
              _x     cut x with those indices ("a"; "bc"; "defg")


Ruby, 55 53 47 45 37 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Dingus
-8 bytes thanks to G B

f=->s,a=1{s&&[s[0,a],*f[s[a..],a+a]]}

Attempt This Online!
@OP just to let you know, the easy tasks are welcome! :)
A recursive function with 2 variables: the original string and the counter. The function chops a string piece, adds it to the unnamed output vector and updates the counter until the string is empty.

I like the recursive way, intuitive but still short. As for easy challenges, I try to intermix them among more medium-difficulty challenges because those tend to be more interesting. but I always have a few of these laying around if I run out of ideas :P

@Dingus thanks for your suggestion! Considering the output, I would rather stick to the output type I have already chosen, as a list.

37 bytes

@GB fantastic! the asterisk is not necessary, or have I missed something?

You get a nested list if you don't "splat". You are not seeing it because puts flattens the result.

Perl 5 -n, 28 bytes
($.*=2)&say$&while s/.{$.}//

Try it online!

Very nice, I came up with a similar (but longer!) approach, using $. is really nice! You can save three bytes using the return of say in the calculation for the increment, and using ; as the delimited for s/// though: Try it online!

05AB1E, 6 bytes
gÝo£õÜ

Try it online.
Or minor alternative:
ā<o£ʒĀ

Try it online.
Explanation:
g       #  Push the length of the (implicit) input-list
 Ý      #  Pop and push a list in the range [0,length]
        # OR:
ā       #  Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length]
 <      #  Decrease each by 1 to the range [0,length)
  o     # Map each value to 2 to the power this value
   £    # Split the (implicit) input-string into parts of those sizes
    õÜ  #  Trim all trailing ""
        # OR:
    ʒ   #  Filter these string-parts:
     Ā  #   Check if truthy (where "" is falsey)
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)


K (ngn/k), 15 bytes
{x@.=+|\2\!-#x}

Try it online!
x:"abcdefg"
!-#x          / integers from -length to -1
  -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
2\!-#x        / convert to base 2
  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   0  0  0  1  1  1  1
   0  1  1  0  0  1  1
   1  0  1  0  1  0  1
|\2\!-#x      / maximum scan
  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
   0  0  0  1  1  1  1
   0  1  1  1  1  1  1
   1  1  1  1  1  1  1
.=+|\2\!-#x   / group identical columns
   (,0; 1 2; 3 4 5 6)
x@.=+|\2\!-#x / index back into the input string
   (,"a"; "bc"; "defg")


Ooh love it! |\2\!-#x is quite clever

Google Sheets, 41 bytes
=index(let(i,2^(row(A:A)-1),mid(A1,i,i)))



you can save 10 bytes by using 2^(row(1:99)-1) instead of 2^sequence(99,1,) and 2^(1+sequence(99,1,-1)).

@z.. right. I was brainless to use two different sequences in the first place. let() saves another 6.

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  66   65   50   49   46   42  41 bytes
-1 byte by doing away with int.bit_length().
-15 bytes: recursion for the win!
-1 byte by using list unpacking instead of list().
-3 bytes by moving some stuff around.
-4 bytes by using and instead of the ternary ... if ... else ....
-1 byte by Jakque.
f=lambda x,n=1:x and[x[:n],*f(x[n:],2*n)]

Try it online!

-1 byte Try it online!

APL+WIN, 20 bytes
Prompts for string. Outputs a nested vector of segments. Index origin = 0
(∊n⍴¨n←2*⍳⌈2⍟⍴s)⊂s←⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Using ⎕IO←1: (r↑i/i←⍳r←⍴s)⊂s←⎕ (or s⊂⍨r↑i/i←⍳r←⍴s←⎕ if you upgrade.)

@Adám. Thanks but your first suggestion results in segments of linear increasing length: a bc def ghij klmno in APL+WIN

Silly me. (r↑i/i←2*⍳r←⍴s)⊆s←⎕ or s⊂⍨r↑i/i←×⍨⍳r←⍴s←⎕ with ⎕IO←0

Charcoal, 13 bytes
Ｅ↨Ｌθ²×ψＸ²κ↑¤θ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｅ↨Ｌθ²×ψＸ²κ

Reserve a number of lines corresponding to the 1s in the base-2 representation of the input length, with each line's length being each power of 2 in turn, according to its index.
↑¤θ

Fill that reserved area using the original input string, thereby partitioning it as required.

Retina 0.8.2, 21 bytes
!`(?<=(.)*).(?<-1>.)*

Try it online! Explanation: The last stage is by default a Match stage if there is no replacement pattern for it to be a Replace stage. The ! changes the output from the number of matches (in decimal) to the matches themselves (on separate lines). The pattern then uses a .NET balancing group to count its match index (which will be one less than a power of 2) and allow one character more than that to be matched.

Jelly, 5 bytes
J2*œṖ

A monadic Link that accepts a list and yields a list of lists.
Try it online!
How?
J2*œṖ - Link: List of characters, S
J     - indices -> [1..len(S)]
 2*   - two exponentiate {that}
   œṖ - partition {S} at {those} indices


JavaScript (V8), 38 bytes
x=>x.replace(/|/g,_=>i&++i?'':' ',i=0)

Try it online!
Separate by space

37 bytes by taking an array of characters as input.

J, 16 bytes
<;.1~1=1#.[:#:#\

Attempt This Online!
<;.1~1=1#.[:#:#\     Input: string of length 2^n-1 (example: 'abcdefg')
              #\     1-based indices (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
          [:#:       each number to binary (0 0 1; 0 1 0; 0 1 1; 1 0 0; ...; 1 1 1)
       1#.           sum the bits of each number (1 1 2 1 2 2 3)
     1=              is it 1? (1 1 0 1 0 0 0)
<;.1~                cut at 1s and box each word ('a'; 'bc'; 'defg')


Pip -p, 10 bytes
a^@--E\,#a

I feel there could be 1 or 2 bytes improvement but I don't see it at the moment.
Attempt This Online!

Ah, nice! My initial solution was 12 bytes, very similar except I didn't think of the fact that too-big values in the argument of ^@ wouldn't make a difference.

A scan-based solution is also 10 bytes.

Japt -m, 9 7 5 bytes
Input as a character array, output as a 2D character array
Wv2pV

Try it

Very nice. TIL -m gives U,V,W the standard .map arguments, I guess it makes sense though. BTW, I'm working on a spiritual-successor to Japt called Vascri which in theory is about as short as Jelly while maintaining Japt/JS familiarity. It's almost ready for a 0.1 release, so you should see some solutions in Vascri popping up pretty soon :)

Vyxal, 3 bytes
ẏEẇ

Try it Online!
Golf pilled sbcs maxxer.
Explained
ẏEẇ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ẏ    # ‎⁡Range [0, len input)
 E   # ‎⁢Each to the power of 2
  ẇ  # ‎⁣Partition the string into groups corresponding to each length


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Nibbles, 17 nibbles (8.5 bytes)
| . `,,$ <;^2$ >-$~ _

Attempt This Online!
  .                     # map over
    `,                  # range from zero to
      ,$                # length of input:
         <              #   take the first
           ^2$          #   2^n characters
          ;             #   (and save that number)
                        #   from
               >        #   drop the first
                -$~     #   saved number minus 1
                        #   characters
                        #   from
                    _   #   the input
|                       # and finally filter-out 
                        # any empty strings


Nibbles, 17 nibbles (8.5 bytes)
\ ! ;`. $ </,$~$ >>@ ~ -

Attempt This Online!
A completely different approach for same bytes: successively halve the string and take pairwise differences.
\ ! ;`. $ </,$~$ >>@ ~ -
     `'                     # iterate while unique
        $                   # starting with the input:
          <                 #   select the first
           /,$~             #   half its length
               $            #   characters
    ;                       # and save this list;
  !                         # now, zip this list with
                 >>@        # itself without the first element:
                     ~ -    #   get differences;
\                           # finally, reverse it

This would be 1 nibble shorter if we're allowed to output the divided segments in reverse order.

Arturo, 34 32 bytes
$=>[i:1chunk&=>[2i'i+1ceil log]]

Try it!
Explanation
$=>[]        ; a function where input is assigned to &
i:1          ; assign 1 to i
chunk&=>[]   ; split input by...
2i ceil log  ; bit length of i
'i+1         ; increment i


I really gotta learn Arturo. It's so pretty!

@noodleperson I love it for golfing because you can do things in a surprising number of orders as well as prefix, infix, and postifx, all of which are shorter in different circumstances.

Brachylog, 12 bytes
{Ẹg|ḍgᵗ↰ʰc}b

Try it online!
Explanation
We rely on ḍ - dichotomize to split the string in 2. When the length is odd, the first string is shorter which is what we want. We then recurse dichotomization on the first string. The tricky part is then to flatten the list recursively up in the same predicate. We use the same idea as @Dlosc answer here, integrated directly in the predicate thas splits the string instead of applied after (which is longer).
{         }     Apply the following predicate on the input string:
 Ẹ                If the input is the empty string ""…
  g                …output [""]
   |              Else
    ḍ             Dichotomize the string [<first half>, <second half>]
     gᵗ           Wrap the second half in a list
       ↰ʰ         Recursive call on the first half
         c        Concatenate to flatten the current level

           b    Remove the first element which is the empty string at the end


PowerShell, 43 bytes
%{for($i=1;$_[$i];$i*=2){$_|% S*g($i-1)$i}}

Try it online!
Straightforward: extract substrings of doubling length at doubling start indexes.
Relevant golfing:

The loop exit condition $_[$i] tests just whether there is still a character at the current index; way shorter than $i-lt$_.Length
$_|% S*g($i-1)$i takes the input string in $_, pipes it to % (an alias for ForEach-Object), calls the string object's member 'Substring' (the only member matching S*g), passing the start index and the length of the substring to retrieve. Shorter than $_.Substring($i-1,$i)


JavaScript (Node.js), 44 bytes
x=>[...x].reduce((a,c,i)=>i&++i?a+c:a+' '+c)

Try it online!

Nice solution! In case you didn't see, @l4m2 posted a JavaScript solution earlier in the thread at 38 bytes: l4m2's solution

C (gcc), 54 50 bytes
-4 bytes thanks to Mukundan314
i;f(s,l){for(i=1;i<l;i*=2)puts(strndup(s+i-1,i));}

Try it online!
May have a memory leak or two.

51 bytes

50 bytes

Thank you, edited.

Haskell + hgl, 22 bytes
This answer was written jointly with 0 '
cr<<<gB(l<bi<st)<zp nN

Attempt This Online!
Explanation

zp nN zip with the natural numbers to pair each element with its 1-index.
gB(l<ni<st) group the list by the length of the index as a binary number.
cr remove the indices

23 bytes
he<pST(fo<pa(eq<db.*l))

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
This implements an exponential time algorithm. Unlike the previous solution this errors when the input is not one less than a power of two in length.

he get the first ..
pST partition of the input such that ...
fo for all ...
pa pairs of consecutive elements ...
eq<db.*l the length of the second is double the length of the first.

Reflection
There are quite a few things I see here to improve.

There should be a version of eu which starts indexing from 1 instead of 0. zp nN is the way we are doing that now.
There should be some log functions for calculating the digit lengths in various bases. Currently this is l<bi.
There should be a function to determine if every pair of consecutive elements in a list satisfies a predicate. This is currently fo<<pa.
There are currently functions for breaking lists into fixed-size chunks. There should be a function which takes a list and spits it into chunks of the sizes given in the list. This would vastly trivialize this challenge.

As of 79db5b20 these reflections are implemented and this answer can be
10 bytes
xuc$pw2<nn

18 bytes
cr<<<gB(lB2<st)<eU

19 bytes
he<pST(apa$eq<db.*l)


Uiua, 11 bytes
⊕□⊚⍜ₙ⇡2+1⧻.

Try it online!
Nice and short! ⊕ (group) and ⊚ (where) are a great combo for this.
⊕□⊚⍜ₙ⇡2+1⧻.  # input string on the right.   "abcdefghijklmno"
       +1⧻.  # length + 1                   16
   ⍜ₙ⇡2      # 2^( range( log_2( that )))   [1 2 4 8]
⊕□⊚          # group into pieces that size  {"a" "bc" "defg" "hijklmno"}

⍜ₙ⇡2 means range (⇡) "under" (⍜) logarithm ₙ base 2. ⍜ applies a function, then a second function, and then the inverse of that first function. Here, we apply log_2(x), then range, and then the inverse of log_2(x) which is 2^x.
Literally, ⊕□⊚ does:
     #                              [1 2 4 8]
⊚    # these repeat the naturals:   [0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
⊕□   # group by boxing the chars     a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
     # corresponding with indices   {"a" "bc" "defg" "hijklmno"}


Uiua, 9 bytes
This solution was written by Kai Schmidt, the creator of Uiua, not by me, so I'm making this a community wiki.
⊕□⌊ₙ2+1°⊏

Try it!
This is a very simple solution, and very short: Take the range of 0 to the length of the input, add one to each, take the base-2 logarithm, and floor it. This list has natural numbers repeated doubling in length, so we use this as a group to take each part of the input into a list of boxes.

Excel, 35 34 bytes
-1 byte thanks to @doubleunary
=LET(i,2^(ROW(A:A)-1),MID(A1,i,i))



Replace 1:99 with A:A to save a byte?

Haskell, 61 58 56 55 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard
♦

takeWhile(>"").evalState(mapM(state.splitAt.(2^))[0..])

Try it online!
It maps (with state) over the infinite sequence of powers of two. Each map step returns the first n characters of the string in the state and puts the remaining in the state. So giving as initial state the string and stop iterating when the result is the empty string, we obtain the result.

The parens around takeWhile are not necessary.

Julia 1.0, 36 bytes
!s=keys(s).|>k->show(s[2^~-k:~-2^k])

Try it online!
Ends with an error. Substrings are printed in quotes. Cleaner output with println instead of show (+3 bytes)

Very nice! Good use of letting it just error out so you don't have to worry about just taking log2 of the length or some shenanigans

Julia 1.0, 54 bytes
~s=[s[2^i:2*2^i-1] for i=0:floor(Int,log2(length(s)))]

Try it online!
Uses array comprehension to generate pairs of indices. The related solution with map takes the same number of bytes:
Julia 1.0, 54 bytes
~s=map(i->s[2^i:2*2^i-1],0:floor(Int,log2(length(s))))

Try it online!

MathGolf, 12 11 bytes
hâΣÆïó‼<≥;]

Try it online.
Explanation:
Step 1: Calculate the amount of parts we need to output, basically \$\log_2(length+1)\$ manually:
          #  (e.g. input = "abcdefghijklmno")
h         # Push the length of the (implicit) input-string
          #  → 15
 â        # Convert it to a binary list
          #  → [1,1,1,1]
  Σ       # Sum this list of 1-bits
          #  → 4

Step 2: Actually split the input into the power of 2 parts:
Æ         # Loop in the range [0,value],
          # using 5 characters as inner code-block:
 ï        #  Push the current 0-based loop-index
  ó       #  Pop and convert it to 2 to the power this index
   ‼      #  Apply the next two operators separately on the current stack:
    <     #   Slice to substring [0,val)
     ≥    #   Slice to substring [val,length)
      ;   # After the loop: discard the trailing no-op part
       ]  # Wrap all correct parts on the stack into a list
          # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)


I'm surprised that a language with "Math" in the name doesn't have logarithm built-in and chose instead to have "5-character block" built-in, lol. (h╥(âΣ would just be ceiling of log_2)

@noodleperson ikr.. I've been missing a lot of Math-related builtins besides logarithm in the past in this language, like sine/cosine/tangent; rounding; base conversion besides binary/hexadecimal; bitwise operations like AND/OR/XOR; etc.

Wow, why on earth is it called MathGolf?! Is it just the fact that it uses Σ to mean sum? :P

@noodleperson I think the idea was to eventually add all the other stuff, but it was mostly abandoned. It does have 59 different 1-byte numeral constants, though (but no way to actually push other numbers consistently). xD

GolfScript, 20 19 bytes
1/.,,{).)&!n*}%]zip

Try it online!

-1 byte: dammit.

J, 16 12 bytes
</.~2<.@^.#\

Attempt This Online!
This is my first time trying to golf in J! I got a lot of help golfing the forks and whatnot. I tried a different method from Bubbler's way and it ended 4 bytes shorter :)
Thanks to ovs for telling me about #\ which is a much shorter way of getting the length-one-range.
Explanation:
</.~2<.@^.#\
</.~          NB. Group the items of the input by
    2<.@^.    NB. floors of the base-2 logarithms of
          #\  NB. the range of 1 to the input's length.
              NB.   (Literally: length of prefixes)


This can actually be 12 bytes borrowing #\ -: 1+i.@# from Bubbler's solution.

Thanks @ovs, I didn't know about #\  to get the indices :)

AWK, 64 52 41 bytes
{for(i=1;i<NF;i=2*i)print substr($0,i,i)}

Use [ -F '' ] flag upon calling awk to separate fields and give us the right number for NF.
{for(i=1;i<length($0);i=2*i)printf substr($0,i,i)FS}

Try it online!
{for(i=1;i<length($0);i=2*i)printf substr($0,i,i)"\n"(y=y y" ")}


{for(i=1;i<length($0);i=2*i) # twice as many letters per
printf substr($0,i,i)        # just the letters we need
"\n"(y=y y" ")}              # whitespace for next line


Hi, you don't need the spaces, that was just for the example to show what the task is :) So you can get rid of this (y=y y" "). I have edited the question body to clear that up.

Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 90 bytes
sub MAIN($i){my $s=$i;for (1,2,4...^*>$s.chars) ->$x {say $s.substr(0,$x);$s.=substr($x)}}

Attempt This Online!
ungolfed:
sub MAIN($i){
    my $s=$i;
    for (1,2,4...^*>$s.chars) ->$x {
        say $s.substr(0,$x);
        $s.=substr($x)
    }
}

straightfowards and uninventive and probably not very golfed but this is my first time doing raku or perl and i wanted to try it out.

You linked the ungolfed program in the ATO link

@noodleperson I sure did. The ungolfed version is exactly the same with additional whitespace, I don't think it really matters (I've tested that it sill functions with it removed, hence why there are still mandatory spaces in the golfed version)

-33 by abusing regexes and containers

Otherwise, -24 making an explicit container anyway

Pyth, 9 bytes
fTcQtM^2U

Try it online!
Takes a string as an input and outputs a list of strings.
        U # create a range 0..length of the string
      ^2  # make them powers of 2
    tM    # decrease by 1
  cQ      # chop the input string Q
fT        # remove empty strings


Haskell, 47 bytes
g n""=[]
g n s|(h,t)<-splitAt n s=h:g(n*2)t
g 1

Try it online!
It returns the answer as a list of strings. This is basically the simplest possible answer. More readably, it might be written like this:
go n "" = []
go n string = chunk : go (n*2) string'
  where (chunk, string') = splitAt n string

